# Get correct sound when button is click in custom listview

Tags: java, android

I have listview with textview ang imagebutton, the sound plays correctly when the button is click but when applying search for the list item,and i clicked the button, the button produce wrong sound.the sounds are placed in raw folder

```
MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListViewAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<DictionaryApp> arrayList = new ArrayList();
String[] cuyuno;
String[] edefinition;
EditText editsearch;
String[] english;
ListView list;
String[] tagalog;
String[] tbaybay;
String[] tdefinition;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.tagalog = new String[]{"alaala", "araw", "baliw", "basura", "kahirapan", "kaibigan", "kakatuwa", "kasunduan", "daluyang-luha", "dambuhala", "dulo", "dukutin", "gawin", "guni-guni", "hagdan", "hintay", "idlip", "idolo", "maganda", "masama", "masarap", "matalino", "nagtanan", "nawala", "pagbibitiw", "paikliin"};
    this.tbaybay = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tbaybay);
    this.tdefinition = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tdefinition);
    this.cuyuno = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cuyuno);
    this.english = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.eword);
    this.edefinition = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.edefinition);
    this.list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    for (int i = 0; i < this.tagalog.length; i++) {
        this.arrayList.add(new DictionaryApp(this.tagalog[i], this.tbaybay[i], this.tdefinition[i], this.cuyuno[i], this.english[i], this.edefinition[i]));
    }
    this.adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, this.arrayList);
    this.list.setAdapter(this.adapter);
    this.editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
    this.editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            MainActivity.this.adapter.filter(MainActivity.this.editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()));
        }
    });
}
}
```

DictionaryApp.java

```
public class DictionaryApp {
private String cuyuno;
private String edefinition;
private String english;
private String tagalog;
private String tbaybay;
private String tdefinition;

public DictionaryApp(String tagalog, String tbaybay, String tdefinition, String cuyuno, String english, String edefinition) {
    this.tagalog = tagalog;
    this.tbaybay = tbaybay;
    this.tdefinition = tdefinition;
    this.cuyuno = cuyuno;
    this.english = english;
    this.edefinition = edefinition;
}

public String getTagalog() {
    return this.tagalog;
}

public String getTbaybay() {
    return this.tbaybay;
}

public String getTdefinition() {
    return this.tdefinition;
}

public String getCuyuno() {
    return this.cuyuno;
}

public String getEnglish() {
    return this.english;
}

public String getEdefinition() {
    return this.edefinition;
}
 }
```

ListViewAdapter.java

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<DictionaryApp> arraylist;
private List<DictionaryApp> dictionaryapplist = null;
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context mContext;
MediaPlayer mp;

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView cuyuno;
    TextView edefinition;
    TextView english;
    ImageButton sound;
    TextView tagalog;
    TextView tbaybay;
    TextView tdefinition;
}

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<DictionaryApp> dictionaryapplist) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.dictionaryapplist = dictionaryapplist;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.mContext);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList();
    this.arraylist.addAll(dictionaryapplist);
 }

public int getCount() {
    return this.dictionaryapplist.size();
}

public DictionaryApp getItem(int position) {
    return (DictionaryApp) this.dictionaryapplist.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return (long) position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
        holder.tagalog = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tagalog);
        holder.tbaybay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tbaybay);
        holder.tdefinition = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tdefinition);
        holder.cuyuno = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cuyuno);
        holder.english = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.english);
        holder.edefinition = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edefinition);
        holder.sound = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.sound);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    holder.tagalog.setText(((DictionaryApp) this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getTagalog());
    holder.tbaybay.setText(((DictionaryApp) this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getTbaybay());
    holder.tdefinition.setText(((DictionaryApp) this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getTdefinition());
    holder.cuyuno.setText(((DictionaryApp) this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getCuyuno());
    holder.english.setText(((DictionaryApp) this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getEnglish());
    holder.edefinition.setText(((DictionaryApp) this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getEdefinition());
    holder.sound.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
    holder.sound.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch ((int) ListViewAdapter.this.getItemId(position)) {
                case R.styleable.View_android_theme /*0*/:
                    ListViewAdapter.this.mp = MediaPlayer.create(ListViewAdapter.this.mContext, R.raw.alaala);
                    ListViewAdapter.this.mp.start();
                    return;
                case R.styleable.View_android_focusable /*1*/:
                    ListViewAdapter.this.mp = MediaPlayer.create(ListViewAdapter.this.mContext, R.raw.araw);
                    ListViewAdapter.this.mp.start();
                    return;
                case R.styleable.View_paddingEnd /*3*/:
                    ListViewAdapter.this.mp = MediaPlayer.create(ListViewAdapter.this.mContext, R.raw.baliw);
                    ListViewAdapter.this.mp.start();
                    return;
                case R.styleable.View_theme /*4*/:
                    ListViewAdapter.this.mp = MediaPlayer.create(ListViewAdapter.this.mContext, R.raw.basura);
                    ListViewAdapter.this.mp.start();
                    return;
                case R.styleable.Toolbar_contentInsetStart /*5*/:
                    ListViewAdapter.this.mp = MediaPlayer.create(ListViewAdapter.this.mContext, R.raw.kaibigan);
                    ListViewAdapter.this.mp.start();
                    return;
                case R.styleable.Toolbar_contentInsetEnd /*6*/:
                    ListViewAdapter.this.mp = MediaPlayer.create(ListViewAdapter.this.mContext, R.raw.kakatuwa);
                    ListViewAdapter.this.mp.start();
                    return;
                case R.styleable.Toolbar_contentInsetLeft /*7*/:
                    ListViewAdapter.this.mp = MediaPlayer.create(ListViewAdapter.this.mContext, R.raw.kasunduan);
                    ListViewAdapter.this.mp.start();
                    return;
                default:
                    return;
            }
        }
    });
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListViewAdapter.this.mContext, SingleItemView.class);
            intent.putExtra("tagalog", ((DictionaryApp) ListViewAdapter.this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getTagalog());
            intent.putExtra("tbaybay", ((DictionaryApp) ListViewAdapter.this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getTbaybay());
            intent.putExtra("tdefinition", ((DictionaryApp) ListViewAdapter.this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getTdefinition());
            intent.putExtra("cuyuno", ((DictionaryApp) ListViewAdapter.this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getCuyuno());
            intent.putExtra("english", ((DictionaryApp) ListViewAdapter.this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getEnglish());
            intent.putExtra("edefinition", ((DictionaryApp) ListViewAdapter.this.dictionaryapplist.get(position)).getEdefinition());
            ListViewAdapter.this.mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    this.dictionaryapplist.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        this.dictionaryapplist.addAll(this.arraylist);
    } else {
        Iterator i$ = this.arraylist.iterator();
        while (i$.hasNext()) {
            DictionaryApp da = (DictionaryApp) i$.next();
            if (da.getTagalog().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                this.dictionaryapplist.add(da);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

What i want to come up is to play the soundsin button in correct position inside the listview when searching...please help, I am new to android...

Answer (score 0):

In your `ListViewAdapter.java` check this line

```
holder.sound.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
```

This describes a lot. When you've implemented a search action, your list get repopulated and the value of the `position` gets changed as well. The value of `position` indicates the actual position of that item in the `ListView`.

Let us consider an example. Suppose, you've 7 items in your list. So the value of the `position` for your second item is 1. (As it starts from 0 for the first item in the list).

Now when you implemented a search and you're searching for a keyword in your list, the list gets smaller with matched items. Now when you call `notifyDatasetChanged` it repopulates the `ListView` and sets the `position` values accordingly. Suppose you've 3 items in your list after searching for a keyword. Those 3 were the second, fifth and seventh item on your previous list. Now if you get the value for the `position` of the 3rd item in your shortened list you're expecting it to return 6? (As this was the seventh item in your previous list) **NO** you'll get 2 for the value of `position` here. I think you might've understood the trick here.

So what can be done in these cases? There are many ways you can keep track of the list items. You can simply maintain a second list which will contain your audio files for sound for each list item and bind each list item with a unique ID. When the item gets clicked, you don't have to look for the `position` value. Just get the unique ID associated with that list item and get the corresponding audio file from the list of audio files you're maintaining.

So I might suggest your **DictionaryApp.java** should look like this.

```
public class DictionaryApp {

  private int id;

  private String cuyuno;
  private String edefinition;
  private String english;
  private String tagalog;
  private String tbaybay;
  private String tdefinition;
}
```

Comment: Can you site an example please,i am new to android...and needed to explore things... i will appreciatr your help...